# Testing a method from a mocked dependency that adds something to a list I pass to it

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing unit tests for some code that calls this function:

`fooHelper.validateFoo(foo, errors);`

It might add sometheing to the errors list, which I would like to simulate. I tried something like:

```
verify(fooHelperMock).validateFoo(eq(foo), argThat(errors -> {
   errors.add("Error message");
   return true;
}))
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Is it even possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve using it using ArgumentCaptor, have a look at article https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor. Something like below might work in your context:

```
verify(fooHelperMock).validateFoo(eq(foo), errorsCaptor.capture());
assertThat(errorsCaptor.getValue().size()).isEqualTo(desiredSize);
```